# Microsoft Interop Library: Cannot open excel workbook in IIS8

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have a function thus:

```
   public static void ProcessWorkSheet(string fileName, string month, string year,
     string thread)
    {
        //version number location
        int version_row = 10;
        int version_column = 2;

        SeedsDBEntities db = new SeedsDBEntities();

        try
        {
            //Instance of Excel
            ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            ExcelApp.Visible = true;

            ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

            WorkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(@fileName, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
            (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)WorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(month);
                    .
                    .

            //the rest of the code
     }
```

I am using Microsoft.Interop library to read from an excel sheet and save it to a database. the issue here is that i get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception when the code tries opening the workbook on IIS 8. It works well on visual studio 2010. What could be the problem.

Comment: I would guess the file path isn't what you're hoping it is (may be the file path is relative in VS but not in IIS, or you're using virtual paths, or parent paths are disabled)

Comment: my path looks like this: `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Reports/Summary/" + this._TemplateName)`

Comment: and at the risk of asking a stupid question, do you have Excel installed on the server?

Comment: @DaveRook That is not stupid. You had to cover the basics. And yes, I do have excel installed

Comment: and lastly, what line throws this error?

Comment: I think **get_Item** returns a range, which you seem to be casting to a Worksheet, but I'm guessing you get your error before that? I think you firstly need to use **System.IO.File.Exists** to check that the file is where you think it is before you try to open it and then try **WorkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(@fileName);** (leaving out all of the other optional values) when you do try to open.

Comment: @DaveRook I get the error where the code tries to open the workbook

Comment: @JMK Infact i just tried that. The File exists. But further research suggests i give the IIS user permission to the excel application. Im trying to figure out how that is done

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: Building on what John just said, why not use a simple library to access the data in the file? Such as [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/), or [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx)?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I have since moved to EPPlus and NPOI. They are much more better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to give IIS User permission to use the Application. Create a folder C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop for 64-bits Systems and set the permission settings to allow for IIS user.